# How to use Jenkins pipeline `options` correctly

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Snippet generator created a `properties` block for me. First run reported

```
WorkflowScript: 1: The properties section has been renamed as of version 0.8. Use options instead. @ line 1, column 1.
   pipeline {
```

Replacing `properties` to `options`results with the following error:

```
Errors encountered validating Jenkinsfile:
WorkflowScript: 4: options can not be empty @ line 4, column 5.
   options([$class: 'ThrottleJobProperty',
```

Here is the full `jenkinsfile` for reference

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    options([[$class: 'ThrottleJobProperty',
            categories: ['xcodebuild'],
            limitOneJobWithMatchingParams: false,
            maxConcurrentPerNode: 0,
            maxConcurrentTotal: 0,
            paramsToUseForLimit: '',
            throttleEnabled: true,
            throttleOption: 'category']])

    stages {
        stage("Empty" {
            steps {
                echo "Do nothing"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

#### TLDR

It's no longer possible to use custom `$class` in the options

> Note that `[$class: 'Foo', arg1: 'something', ...]` syntax can not be used, only `booleanParam(...)` and the like.

#### Full Options Syntax

- *Description*: Traditional `JobProperty`s, such as `buildDiscarder` or `disableConcurrentBuilds`, Declarative-specifc options, such as `skipDefaultCheckout`, and "wrappers" that should wrap the entire build, such as `timeout`.
- *Required*: No
- *Allowed In*: Top-level `pipeline` closure only.
- *Parameters*: None
- *Takes a Closure*: Yes
- *Closure Contents*: A sequence of one or more Declarative option or job property configurations, using `@Symbol` names for constructors.

  - Note that `[$class: 'Foo', arg1: 'something', ...]` syntax can not be used, only `booleanParam(...)` and the like.
  - Note that the `parameters` and `pipelineTriggers` `@Symbol`s cannot be used here directly.

Example:

```
options {
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr:'1'))
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/blob/master/SYNTAX.md#options)

Comment: Very helpful, but any idea why snipped Generator still generate old code? A bug in it?

Comment: I've raised this issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35393

Comment: Any alternative that allows to use the old syntax `[$class: 'Foo', arg1: 'something', ...]`? I am in the need of using `HudsonNotificationProperty`

Comment: While I'm not sure if this is officially supported I think you just need to move the properties block to be before the pipeline DSL declaration and it will work.

For an example using the HudsonNotificationProperty see [this comment](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-41939?focusedCommentId=407357&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-407357)

Answer (score 6):

its work for me.

```
properties([parameters([choice(choices: 'test\ndeploy', name: 'baranch')])])
pipeline{
agent any

stages{
    stage('param check'){
        when {
            expression{
                params.baranch == 'test'
            }
        }
        steps{
            echo "testing"
    }
    }
}
```

}