# How to use conditions in Jenkins declarative pipeline "options" block?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I would like to configure the `buildDiscarder` differently depending on a global variable. Currently I have

```
options {
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5'))
}
```

but I'm looking for something like

```
// BROKEN
options {
    if ("${SOME_VAR}" == 'some_val') {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5'))
    } else {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(daysToKeepStr: '7'))
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this kind of behaviour in a Jenkins declarative pipeline? I don't think I can use a `script`/`when`/`expression` block here, or at least it didn't work when I tried.

Sources/ideas that I've stumbled upon which didn't work: [1](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53490266/5018771), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41884503/5018771), [4](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000237071-How-do-I-set-discard-old-builds-for-a-Multi-Branch-Pipeline-Job), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39542485/5018771), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47216731/5018771)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
options {
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: ("${SOME_VAR}" == 'some_val') ? '5' : '7'))
}
```

If you want to use different arguments, just set the "unused" one to `'-1'`:

```
options {
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(
            numToKeepStr: ("${SOME_VAR}" == 'some_val') ? '5' : '-1',
            daysToKeepStr: ("${SOME_VAR}" == 'some_val') ? '-1' : '7'
    ))
}
```